# Как передать параметры через GET-запрос

Tags: javascript, html, django

Я начинающий и не знаю как отправить все необходимые параметры странице, которую хочу открыть. Имеется страница с url `sklad`. Для открытия страницы sklad, ей необходимо передать все необходимые параметры GET-запросом (какие именно параметры нужно отправить, точно не знаю, но имеется сам код страницы `sklad`).

Таким образом запускается страница `sklad`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('{% url 'sklad' %}', '_blank')">
    Расписание
</button>
```

`sklad` = `"/gorod/sklad"`

Как просмотреть параметры, которые отправляются моим GET-запросом, если страница не может быть запущена по причине не подходящих передаваемых параметров GET-запросом? Прошу описать максимально подробно и без использования php.

Использую Django 1.6

Comment: Необходимые параметры обычно должны быть видны в описании нужного view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В джанге нет необходимости передавать параметры в get. В джанге нужные переменные можно включать в адресную строку, которую можно разобрать в конфигурации url.

Вот документация как это надо делать: http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/http/urls.html

Если же всё равно надо методом get, то выглядит это так:

```
http://some-site.ru?var1=value&var2=value2"
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что надо! Но в своем вопросе я изначально не указал версию Django (сейчас добавил), так что в моем случае больше подходит http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/intro/tutorial03.html

Answer (score 1):

GET-параметры передаются очень просто:

```
{% url 'sklad' %}?key=value
```

---

Если же вы имеете в виду параметры из пути, которые вы указали при регистрации роута:

```
url(r'^sklad/(?P<sklad_id>[0-9]+)$', 'apps.panel.views.sklad', name='sklad')
```

Такие параметры передаются в функцию `url`:

```
{% url 'sklad' sklad_id=row_id %}
```